# module 'statsmodels.tsa.api' has no attribute 'arima_model'

Tags: python-3.x, statistics, time-series, arima

I'm trying to use "statsmodels.api" to work with time series data and trying to fit a simple ARIMA model using

```
sm.tsa.arima_model.ARIMA(dta,(4,1,1)).fit()
```

but I got the following error

```
module 'statsmodels.tsa.api' has no attribute 'arima_model'
```

I'm using '`statsmodels`' version 0.9.0 with '`spyder`' version 3.2.8 I'd be pleased to get your help thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The correct path is :

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
sm.tsa.ARIMA()
```

You can view it using a shell that allows autocomplete like `ipython`.

It is also viewable in the example provided by statsmodels such as [this one](http://www.statsmodels.org/stable/examples/notebooks/generated/tsa_arma_0.html).

And more informations about package structure may be found [here](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/api-structure.html).

Comment: The new link to package structure documentation is [here](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/api-structure.html)